# Short story about a world government planting poison kill switches in everybody's head

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a question about a short story I read in Norwegian back in the day, in a kind of (monthly? quarterly?) youths' anthology (not a sci-fi anthology, but a collection of youth-related topics; peer pressure, menstruation, eating disorders, that kind of thing also definitely figured in the same series, or even zine) ca. 1990. Or, at least I think it was in Norwegian. I honestly couldn't remember at this point.

The story was about a planet-spanning civilization with colonies on at least the Moon, where a population-wide crime deterrent existed in the form of a capsule of hydrogen cyanide implanted in the base of every citizen's skull.  They could be activated at will by the governing body to terminate a citizen in response to criminal activity.

The wife of the main character was terminated by this means in response for exceeding her quota on import of 'Moonshine' following a trip to the moon. Possibly the main character's children had similar fates, leading the main character to decide to turn the system on its creators and wipe out *everyone* with the countermeasure with some clever hacking.

The story ends, as far as I remember, with the main character/narrator getting in the bath with a glass of wine waiting for the end to come.

Comment: Was the original language Norwegian, or was it translated? Also, can you remember the name of the anthology?

Comment: @Adamant I think it must have been translated from English. As for the name, no, I can't.